How to do parallel model training for each spark partition in using sparklyR for R?
To me it seems like it should be a straight-out-of-the-box feature when working with spark data tables, but I can simply not find out how to train one model per spark partition (or some sort of grouping) using sparklyR in R.
I am aware of the spark_apply() function, but it seems to be tailored for user defined functions which are not already available in Spark.
I want something like the below where the linear model is fitted on each group (it could also be on each partition). The problem with the below model is that its the global fit (across both groups), and not two separate fits (one for each group).
library(sparklyr)

# Make data
set.seed(134)
n <- 10
x <- 1:n
y <- -x + rep(c(10, 20), each = 5) + rnorm(n)
df <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = n/2),
  y = y,
  x = x
)

# Make Spark data frame
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
sdf <- copy_to(sc, df, name = "sdf")

# Fit linear model
sdf %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  ml_linear_regression(y ~ x)

How can I fit one model for each group or partition?

Is that supposed to be x instead of x1 in y <- -x1 + rep(c(10, 20), each = 5) + rnorm(n)?

Whoops. Yes. That was a typo.

I don't know Spark so this may be irrelevant, but in base R you can fit a single model for every categorical group simultaneously with an interaction term in the formula. So if you switch from lm(y~x) to lm(y~x*group) you'll get the same information as fitting lm(df[df$group=="A",], formula=y~x) and lm(df[df$group=="B",], formula=y~x) separately.

Spark Mllib is designed for out of the box ML models. Otherwise, use UDF. E.g., SparkR has two ways: gapply works on each group, dapply works on each partition, parallelly. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/reference/gapply.html
